# Rails 'service objects' best practice - class method or instantiate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am implementing 'service objects' as per a workshop I've been studying, I'm building a reddit API application. I need the object to return something, so I can't just execute everything in the initializer. I have these two options:

Option1: Class needs instantiating

```
class SubListFromUser

  def user_subscribed_subs(client)
    @client = client
    @subreddits = sort_subs_by_name(user_subs_from_reddit)
  end

  private

  def sort_subs_by_name(subreddits)
    subreddits.sort_by { |sr| sr[:name].downcase }
  end 

  def user_subs_from_reddit
    @client.subscribed_subreddits :limit => 100
  end

end
```

Called with:

```
@subreddits = SubListFromUser.new(@client).user_subscribed_subs
```

---

Or Option2 is having it as a class method:

```
class SubListFromUser

  def self.user_subscribed_subs(client)
    sort_subs_by_name(client, user_subs_from_reddit)
  end

  private

  def self.sort_subs_by_name(subreddits)
    subreddits.sort_by { |sr| sr[:name].downcase }
  end 

  def self.user_subs_from_reddit(client)
    client.subscribed_subreddits :limit => 100
  end

end
```

Called with:

```
@subreddits = SubListFromUser.user_subscribed_subs(@client)
```

What is considered 'best practice' in this situation? Is there a reason I shouldn't be using object.new(args).method? I think it gives a cleaner service class but I'm not sure of the technicalities of this approach and if it has disadvantages.

Edit: Or option3 - I'm going about this all wrong and there is a better approach :)

Comment: you opinion 2 cant work, you use class method `self.user_subscribed_subs(client)` and set instance variable `@client = client` now this `@client.subscribed_subreddits` raise error because  `@client` return `nil`

Comment: It does actually work but I didn't think about instance variables, you're right I should take them out. I did the changes quickly for this post and forgot to change them, apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby, I don't find that there's much of a difference.

I find the use of class variables in your "static" version a bit disturbing.

I think the class version might lead to more-creative re-use through subclassing, but that brings its own set of headaches unless things are designed as correctly as possible.

Comment: Agreed on the disturbing use of instance variables, I didn't think about that. I do prefer the 'class version myself and am trying to get this as 'correct' as possbile for this demo app I'm working on. I just wanted to make sure it wasn't a big no no approaching it the new class way so appreciate your input!

Answer (score 5):

In many cases you'll need to keep a state for the process lifecycle, such as the `client`. Instead of having it "travel" through all methods you need it, as an argument, it makes more sense to keep it as a class variable. But for the sake of cleaner syntax, I recommend to combine the two approaches:

```
class SubListFromUser
  def initialize(client)
    @client = client
  end
  private_class_method :new # only this class can create instances of itself

  def user_subscribed_subs
    @subreddits = sort_subs_by_name(user_subs_from_reddit)
  end

  private

  def sort_subs_by_name(subreddits)
    subreddits.sort_by { |sr| sr[:name].downcase }
  end 

  def user_subs_from_reddit
    @client.subscribed_subreddits :limit => 100
  end


  class << self
    def user_subscribed_subs(client)
      new(client).user_subscribed_subs # create instance of this class and run a process
    end
  end
end
```

Call as a class method:

```
@subreddits = SubListFromUser.user_subscribed_subs(@client)
```