# Ruby: Why instantiate an object and use an instance method when a class method would suffice?

Tags: ruby, class, design-patterns, memory, methods

I am trying to learn design patterns by reading code that has been written by other people. Recently I've been focusing on the difference between class methods and instance methods.

In some code I was reading, I came across the following use of an instance method:

```
class Foo
  def bar!(baz)
    # do something to baz
  end
end

my_foo = Foo.new
my_foo.bar!(baz)
```

Why use an instance method here? The `Foo` class only exists to do `bar`, so why not just use a class method? From what I've been learning, my inclination would've been do to this:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar!(baz)
    # do something to baz
  end
end

Foo.bar!(baz)
```

Is there any reason to go with the first pattern? Is it just a matter of preference? My thought was that making an object uses memory and so the first one is actually inefficient, but am looking for any advice from more experienced folks. Thanks!

Comment: This blog from CodeClimate makes a fairly solid point about class methods resisting refactoring, which might something to consider if the method is likely to be especially complex: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/11/14/why-ruby-class-methods-resist-refactoring/
Class methods also make it much easier to introduce accidental global variables, which are generally considered poor design.
Finally, as mentioned in the linked article, the memory needed to instantiate one object is likely negligible to your code's performance (but if there are many instantiations, its worth benchmarking).

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to prefer the former over the latter. Instantiating a class could cause a slight performance hit due to the GC doing more work, but I think you should really be asking yourself this question:

> Is there ever any reason to create multiple instances of the class?

I.e. could you just do `foo = Foo.new` and then use `foo` everywhere? If so, you don't need a class at all. In fact, a similar argument applies to your second example. While it is an improvement over the first, there is still no reason to create instances of the class. So don't use a class, use a module.

```
module Foo
  def self.bar(baz)
  end
end
```

Comment: Modules for the win if you don't need to instantiate something!

Answer (score 2):

If the method you are invoking is idempotent (i.e. you can call it many times without side-effects and always obtaining the same result) and does not depend on the state of the object (i.e. you don't need to initialize the class object), using a static method is absolutely fine.

```
Foo.bar!(baz)
```

If instead the method has side-effects, or its result depends on the state of the object, it is better to create an instance of Foo, configure it and then invoke your method

```
foo = Foo.new(some_value)
foo.other_value = value_2
foo.bar!(baz)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no much difference in your case.

Using classes make your code:

- More creative,
- Re-useable through subclassing,
- Pass your argument once when initalizing and then use it else where in your functions, without the need to pass same arguments to each function call.

so any class methods can be replaced with instance method and work, for more abstraction.

---

```
class Foo
  def initialize baz
    @baz = baz
  end

  def bar!
   # do something to @baz
  end

  def another_function_use_baz
   # do something to @baz
  end
end

my_foo = Foo.new(baz)
my_foo.bar!
my_foo.another_function_use_baz
```

[Check also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780526/rails-service-objects-best-practice-class-method-or-instantiate)

Answer (score 0):

If the method *only* does something to its arguments, and does not make any use of `self`, e.g. by calling another instance method or accessing an instance variable (either directly or indirectly), then it does indeed not make sense for it to be an instance method.

In fact, it does not make sense for it to be a method *at all*. It's a procedure or a function. However, Ruby doesn't really have procedures or functions (except for `Proc` objects, of course), so the closest thing we usually do is either a `private` instance method of `Kernel` (for example like `puts` or `require`) or an instance method of some singleton class, like `Math::abs` or `Math::log`. This depends largely on whether the procedure is globally useful or should be namespaced.

If that really is the only method the class has, then the *usual* way to write it would indeed be like:

```
module Foo
  def self.bar!(baz)
    # do something to baz
  end
end
```

or maybe like this, which would additionally allow you to `include` `Foo` to get rid of the namespacing.

```
module Foo
  module_function

  def bar!(baz)
    # do something to baz
  end
end
```

Whereas *I* would probably write it like this:

```
def (Foo = BasicObject.new).bar!(baz)
  # do something to baz
end
```

By the way: that method violates one general and one Ruby coding standard: in general, functions, procedures, methods, etc. should *not* modify their arguments, whereas your comment seems to indicate that the method does modify `baz` ("do something **to** `baz`"). And in Ruby, there should only be a method named with a bang (`!`) to indicate a more surprising version of another method named without a bang. In other words, there should only be a `bar!` method if there is also a `bar` method.

Answer (score 0):

@Marco Sandrini was right in my opinion but to add to that...
You can have a Math class that has Pi set, and has methods that you call with your own arguments and they dont rely on the state of the object

Whereas if you have a Student class you would require certain states like DOB if you call jonny.getAge() as it would require jonny's DOB which would be different than sally's age.